# セルが使いまわされた時にセル内の画像が重なる

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

iPhoneの画面が回転して横向きになったときに`AutoLayout`を使って`TableView`のセル内の`ScrollView`を画面いっぱいまで伸ばし、ひとまず下記の画像のようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、`TableView`を上のセルが見えなくなるまでスクロールし、また上のセルまで戻ってくると以下の画像のようになってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これは`TableView`のセルの使い回しが影響しているものと思うのですが、どうすれば画像が重なることを回避することができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

---追記---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static const id identifiers[5] = {@"normalCell", @"cell", @"detailCell", @"halfCell", @"normalCell"};
    NSString *CellIdentifier = identifiers[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell = [[NormalScrollCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                break;
            case 1:
                cell = [[PagerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                break;
            case 2:
                cell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                break;
            case 3:
                cell = [[HalfPager alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                break;
            default:
                cell = [[NormalScrollCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                break;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「追記」を見て、ようやくわかりました。
プログラムでセルを生成しているのなら、いくらAutoLayoutを、Storyboard上で編集しても、意味ありません。**alloc+init**で生成したインスタンスは、Storyboard上のインスタンスと、おなじクラスであっても、別物です。

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

このメソッドでなく、

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

を使ってください。Storyboard上で、Prototype Cellsに正しくIdentifierが設定されていれば、`if (cell == nil)`以下のコードが不用になります。

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static const id identifiers[5] = {@"normalCell", @"cell", @"detailCell", @"halfCell", @"normalCell"};
    NSString *CellIdentifier = identifiers[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

これだと、Storyboard上のセルに対するAutoLayoutの設定が反映されます。
また、副産物で、テーブルビュー表示にかかる時間が、わずかでも短くなる、ということです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示いただいた方法で実装するとセル内の画像が重なることなく表示されました！Storyboardのセルの扱い方が理解できました。本当に感謝しています。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

cellForRowAtIndexPathではどのようにcellの描画をしていますか？
以前私が同じような事象になった際は
cellForRowAtIndexPathで一度cell内のsubviewを削除しました。

```
for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

他にもっと良い方法があるかもしれませんが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
cellForRowAtIndexPathでのcellの描画に関する部分を追記しました。
ご提示の方法でsubviewを削除してみたのですが、cellが全て消えてしまいました。。。

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPathのどの部分でremoveされましたか？
上記追記ソースでいうと
UITableViewCell *cell =　[self.tableView deq...
と　
if (cell == nil) {...
の間に追記しても全部消えてしまうでしょうか？

Comment: はい、その部分にremoveFromSuperviewの処理を書いたのですが、セルの中身が全て消えてしまいました。

Comment: 解決できてよかったです。
お力になれずすみません。

Comment: いえいえ、解決に協力してくださりとても感謝しています。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。
カスタムCellを使用していると思うのですが、Cellの高さ計算があっていないのではないでしょうか？
私もCellがオーバーラップして表示された時がありました。
このメソッドで正しいCellの値が返されていますか？


`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。初めまして。
heightForRowAtIndexPathではセルごとに高さを固定して返しています。

Comment: なるほど。。。
今回は高さではなく横幅ですね。すみません勘違いをしておりました。
おそらく推測ですが、AutoLayoutのサイズが確定する前にcellのサイズが設定されているのかもしれません。
cellForRowAtIndexPath内ではCellは正しいサイズになっていますか？

Comment: すみません、わからないことが多く質問させていただきたいのですが、Cellの正しいサイズというのは、どうであれば正しいのでしょうか？
現在セルの高さは固定しているのですが、固定じゃなくて可変にしなくてはいけないのでしょうか？